# How can I un-brick my OnePlus One?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, unbricking, oneplus-one

While installing a custom ROM on my OnePlus One, I accidentally wiped the INTERNAL STORAGE of my phone, thus wiping the zip files of the ROM and Gapps.
So I'm stuck with only the recovery, but no OS.
Upon reboot, the screen is stuck one the OnePlus logo.
I've tried using adb push and adb sideload but 'adb devices' does not recognize my device. However, fastboot does recognize it.
How do I install a ROM and get my phone to work again?

Comment: Hope this helps
[Un-brick Oneplus One](http://www.android.gs/unbrick-oneplus-one/)

Comment: Seems like your device is stuck in its boot loop. From XDA developers, try [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-one/general/guide-unbrick-oneplus-one-t3013732). Might help.

Comment: Download a ROM that's specifically for your device, then connect your phone to the computer and use `fastboot update <path/to/your/file.zip>` to flash the package.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked the question 15 days ago, did you manage to get your device working again? What steps did you take? I'll give it a go in case anyone needs it.

As I've experienced, having a USB OTG cable laying around can be most useful with this device. You can find them cheap just about anywhere. They convert any USB storage device you have to external memory for your One. Just connect it to your device and mount it in TWRP (or any recovery that supports it). Don't forget to unmount it or you'll run into trouble later on.

It does sound like you didn't get the drivers right if no device popped up with adb. You can install these generic [Samsung drivers](http://d-h.st/aJlr) to make it work.

Another thing, if you're having issues in TWRP, it could be useful to flash a different version via fastboot. I'm using [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24399994186369589) on my OnePlus One to flash Resurrection Remix M and it hasn't let me down yet.